# Magento 2.2.5 Unable to Upgrade Database

Tags: magento2, database, error, magento-2.2.5, magento-upgrade

We just upgraded out Magento to version 2.2.5, and when going to the website we are confronted with this error:

https://pastebin.com/LkjaGxC6

Upon running the command, in the CLI we are then greeted with this error and are unsure where to move from here, thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX8Dm.png

UPDATE: Failing MySQL Query: https://pastebin.com/ANixuM9N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually created the database using phpmyadmin and the query that was provided in the error. 
Ran bin/magento setup:upgrade and issue was fixed.